# Disable implicit binding in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel 5.2, I usually bind  my objects between routes and controller.

In my Routes.php, I have:

```
     Route::resource('tournaments', 'TournamentController', ['names' => ['edit' => 'tournaments.edit', 'update' => 'tournaments.update']]);
```

In my Controller, I have:

```
public function edit($tournament){  
  ...
}
```

and $tournament already has been binded to Tournament Object.

This is not a useful query because just after that, I do:

```
        $tournament = Tournament::with('competitors','categoryTournaments.settings', 'categoryTournaments.category')->find($tournament->id);
```

So, I would like not to have implicit binding in this case,I would be glad to receive id instead, is it posible???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit Model Binding is Activated if you Hinted the Model Associated with that Variable...

By Default it is not active it is only Active When you do so like this

```
use App\Tournament;

public function edit(Tournament $tournament){  
//
}
```

Comment: you are right, I have found my mistake, I had defined explicit binding! tx for your help